# VBA: List all files and their files paths in a column and grab cell value from each workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master excel workbook with other excel workbook file paths and file names listed in column D (from row D17) onwards:

```
Row D17       C:\D\Folder1\File1.xls
Row D18       C:\D\Folder2\File2.xls
Row D19       C:\D\Folder3\File3.xls
```

This list starts from D17 onwards and could potentially be 3 to 100 rows +, depending on the number of files in the directory.

I am using VBA to pull a list of folders and their corresponding files inside of my 'D' folder on the C drive.

This results in the file path and the excel file name being listed like above.

Each of these workbooks contains an email address inside of them in cell C15 which I want to copy and paste into the adjacent cell of my master workbook like so:

```
C:D\\Folder1\File1.xls       email@ForFile1.com
C:\D\Folder2\File2.xls       email@ForFile2.com
C:\D\Folder3\File3.xls       email@ForFile3.com
```

At the moment my code lists all the files but only checks the first instance of the workbook in row D17 and only grabs the email address for that one workbook:

```
C:\D\Folder1\File1.xls       email@ForFile1.com
C:\D\Folder2\File2.xls       
C:\D\Folder3\File3.xls
```

I know why this is, because I have only told my code to check the first workbook in cell D17 - but I am brand new to VBA and do not know how I can get my code to loop through each workbook in my list and copy and paste the relevant email address into the adjacent cell.

Please can someone show me how to do this?

Here is my code:

```
Sub SO()

Dim parentFolder As String

parentFolder = Range("F11").Value & "\" '// change as required, keep trailing slash

Dim results As String

results = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & parentFolder & "*.*"" /S /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll

Debug.Print results

'// uncomment to dump results into column A of spreadsheet instead:
Range("D17").Resize(UBound(Split(results, vbCrLf)), 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Split(results, vbCrLf))
Range("Z17").Resize(UBound(Split(results, vbCrLf)), 1).Value = "Remove"
'//-----------------------------------------------------------------
'// uncomment to filter certain files from results.
'// Const filterType As String = "*.exe"
'// Dim filterResults As String
'//
'// filterResults = Join(Filter(Split(results, vbCrLf), filterType), vbCrLf)
'//
'// Debug.Print filterResults
On Error GoTo errHandler
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Dim app As New Excel.Application
app.Visible = False 'Visible is False by default, so this isn't necessary

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open(Range("D17").Value)
Set y = ThisWorkbook

'Now, copy what you want from x:
x.Worksheets(1).Range("C15").Copy

'Now, paste to y worksheet:
y.Worksheets(1).Range("U17").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Close x:
x.Close


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

errHandler:
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Comment: this question appears to be the same as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637137/vba-get-email-address-from-each-workbook-in-a-range): if you're not satisfied with answers you already got there then improve _that_ question till closing the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vba get email address from each workbook in a range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637137/vba-get-email-address-from-each-workbook-in-a-range)

Comment: @user3598756 thank you for your comment. Please note that i have already attempted to improve and provide additional supporting comments around that question. The answers provided do not sufficiently provide the correct resolution.

Comment: your _original_ post has many clarifications and thoughts you already exchanged with people trying at helping you. while here you'd have people start anew and loosing time. please stick to your previous post and try enhancing it. on the other hand you can partecipate to SO and earn reputation enough to start a bounty on your issue

Comment: I've posted an answer on your original post. As others have said, you really ought to close this post and stick to your original question. SO has some very bright and creative thinkers; the reason the "answers provided do not sufficiently provide the correct resolution" is that your post does not articulate the correct question.