# vba get value from multiple workbooks listed in a column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with other workbooks listed down column G

```
Folder\File1.xls
Folder\File2.xls
Folder\File3.xls
Folder\File4.xls
```

The below vba code gets the email address from cell C15 in all of these workbooks and adds them to column U like so:

```
Folder\File1.xls          Email
Folder\File2.xls          Email
Folder\File3.xls          Email
Folder\File4.xls          Email
```

This is my code.

```
'//Email copy code

Dim startCell As Range, fileRng As Range
Dim files As Variant, values() As Variant, values2() As Variant
Dim path As String, file As String, arg As String
Dim r As Long, i As Long

'Acquire the names of your files
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 'amend to your sheet name
    Set startCell = .Range("G17") 'amend to start cell of file names
    Set fileRng = .Range(startCell, .Cells(.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp))
End With
files = fileRng.Value2

'Size your output array
ReDim values(1 To UBound(files, 1), 1 To 1)


'Populate output array with values from workbooks
For r = 1 To UBound(files, 1)
    'Create argument to read workbook value
    i = InStrRev(files(r, 1), "\")
    path = Left(files(r, 1), i)
    file = Right(files(r, 1), Len(files(r, 1)) - i)
    arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]Sheet1'!R15C3"
    'Acquire the value
    values(r, 1) = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)

Next


'Write values to sheet
fileRng.Offset(, 20).Value = values
```

This code works on my windows laptop at home. However, at work, my IT department disable the use of CMD and other shell functions - which i believe this code uses to grab the value from the workbooks.

As a result, this code doesn't get the value from column C15.

Can anyone give me a workaround? Thanks

Comment: Ok, for one thing that code looks a lot like the code I gave you yesterday (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637137/vba-get-email-address-from-each-workbook-in-a-range/41657368#41657368) - you should at least reference your sources; and for another, 7 questions in 2 days with only two accepted answers is a pretty poor show and not how this site works. Perhaps you should show some grace for all the work you are asking of others.

Answer (score 0):

How about this workaround:

```
arg = path & "[" & file & "]Sheet1'!R15C3"
'Acquire the value
values(r, 1) = arg
'values(r, 1) = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
```

Would this work? What does it produce? What should it produce?

Comment: this doesnt seem to work. It should give me an email address from cell C15 from the workbook. Instead, your code is giving me the workbook path, see below:

Comment: 'G:\BUYING\Food Specials\2. Planning\3. Confirmation and Delivery\Announcements\2017\KW11\Multy\[Multy KW11.17.xlsx]Sheet1'!R15C3

Comment: Can you try again? :)

Comment: thanks tried again and whilst the code looks like its bringing up the cmd window for a split second, the same result as before is given